# How to scroll webview up to view previous page and scroll down to view next page display in android

Tags: android

My application is similar to ebook reader app. reading text from text files to view on WebView. When the user is scrolling to the bottom of the page, i want to load the next page and when he is scrolling upwards, i want to load the previous page. Anyone have any idea of implementing this one, please share me.

Comment: If you have any examples, that would be great for me.

Comment: i think u need to reload the webview again on click of android native button click

Comment: @Monika Can you give me more detail ...

Comment: u want next page and previous page concept right?

Comment: it is similar to ebook reader and view on WebView.

Comment: ok got you , tell me one think u know what content is to ddisplayed on particular page nunmber?

Comment: I have a long book with many sections. I divide them into sections and consider as one sections is one page number. When user read any section, user can scroll up and down. when he scroll up to load the page before current page. when he scroll down to load the page after the current page. is that what you mean?

Comment: i mean when user press back or next button the content must refresh the webview

Comment: @Android_Beginner why are you editing my post. If you have a new question you should start a new thread. Your edit is reject by the community